# Collect is not giving me the result I expect

Tags: algebraic-manipulation

When I evaluate

```
Collect[(a ((G m ω)/c^3)^(1/2) + b ((G m ω)/c^3)^(1/2)), c]
```

I get this:

> ```
> a Sqrt[(G m ω)/c^3] + b Sqrt[(G m ω)/c^3]
> ```

Here is a snapshot of the output.

[image: The actual unwanted output]

So, both `c`-terms are not being collected together. I have `c` in two different terms in the expanded form.

I expected the following:

[image: expected output]

How can I get the form I want?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I believe that Collect does exactly what it is intended to do here.

Comment: I have edited my question. Please see if it can be put off hold.

Comment: I don't get it. You ask Mathematica to collect powers of `a` and that is precisely what it does. There is one zeroth order term and a first order term in `a`. Why you expect it to work on `c` is an enigma to me.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries , hey, yeah, the question got wrong. It should be 'c' there - ' b ((G m ω)/c^3)^(1/2)), c]'. But even with 'c', it doesn't collect c at a single place. But the method suggested by Karsten 7. works.

Comment: OK, with that correction your question is open again.

Comment: Or see the comment by @Karsten 7 attached below the question itself.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
    expr = (a ((G m \[Omega])/c^3)^(1/2) + b ((G m \[Omega])/c^3)^(1/2));

Simplify[expr, {G > 0, c > 0, m > 0, \[Omega] > 0}]

(*   (a + b) Sqrt[(G m \[Omega])/c^3]   *)
```

Have fun!

Answer (score 3):

You can get the desired output using

```
PowerExpand[(a ((G m ω)/c^3)^(1/2) + b ((G m ω)/c^3)^(1/2)), c] // Together
```

$\frac{a \sqrt{G m \omega }+b \sqrt{G m \omega }}{c^{3/2}}$

as

```
PowerExpand[(a ((G m ω)/c^3)^(1/2) + b ((G m ω)/c^3)^(1/2)), c]
```

$\frac{a \sqrt{G m \omega }}{c^{3/2}}+\frac{b \sqrt{G m \omega }}{c^{3/2}}$
gets `c` out of the square roots and `Together` converts the sum into a single rational function.